# Scala overloaded higher-order functions cause type error

Tags: scala, types, overloading

I have a overloaded method defined as follows:

```
def g(f: () ⇒ Double): Object = null
def g(f: Double ⇒ Double): Object = null
def g(f: (Double, Double) ⇒ Double): Object = null

def h(f: (Double, Double) ⇒ Double): Object = null
```

While `h(math.max _)` works as expected, calling `g(math.max _)`
gives me the error "Overloaded method... cannot be applied to ((Int, Int) => Int)". It seems that the compiler chose the Int version of `math.max` instead of the Double version.

How can I call my overloaded method `g` with math.max as a parameter? It would be an added bonus if I could just call `g(math.max)` without the underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've run into a heuristic used by the compiler to help avoid exponentially complex searches for types.  When the method is overloaded, it tries to disambiguate based on the type of the argument.  Unfortunately, the argument is *also* overloaded.  Instead of trying out possibilities, it just grabs the first one that comes to mind and it doesn't work.

You can trick it into searching more by asking the right way:

```
g(math.max(_,_))
```

Notationally it's now clear to the compiler that it's looking for a `Function2` and that--even though all versions of `max` must be `Function2`!--is enough to get the compiler to search for a match (and it matches `Double` with `Double`).

Answer (score 1):

Minutes after posting this, I discovered this solution:

```
g(math.max: ((Double, Double) => Double))
```

I'm still curious why Scala has the issue in the first case.

Comment: As Rex pointed out, `max` is an overloaded method and has four alternatives. Obviously only the max(Double,Double) works but the inferrer just isn't smart enough to see it.